# Python, How to give a 2D list of values the same coordinates excel has

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a 2D list that has rows and columns but I want to insert the coordinate values on the same format that excel would have like the [0][0] location would be A1. How would I go about doing this?
Thanks

Comment: how many rows and columns ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a function to convert the excel index to array indices and then use them (that would be the most performant solution i think)

```py
import re

def excel_to_idx(excel_coords):
  col_letters, row = re.search(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", excel_coords).groups()
  col2num = lambda col: reduce(lambda x, y: x*26 + y, [ord(c.upper()) - ord('A') + 1 for c in col])
  return int(row) - 1, col2num(col_letters)


# and use it
row, col = excel_to_idx("AAAAA1111111")
array[row][col]
```